# Como saber quantos objetos foram instanciados?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, instanciar-objeto

Em uma aplicação Java, como faço para saber quantos objetos de uma classe foram instanciados? Essa dúvida me surgiu lendo o artigo mencionado no link abaixo. Segue o trecho que me gerou a dúvida:

> **2.4 - Fábrica de Conexões**
>
> *Em determinado momento de nossa aplicação, gostaríamos de ter o
>   controle sobre a construção dos objetos da nossa classe. Muito pode
>   ser feito através do construtor, como saber quantos objetos foram
>   instanciados ou fazer o log sobre essas instanciações.*

Fonte: [Caelum](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/bancos-de-dados-e-jdbc/#2-4-fabrica-de-conexoes)

Comment: Não sei se é exatamente isso que você está procurando, então vou deixar como comentário: Para contar a quantidade de objetos instanciados você pode usar uma variável estática (e.g., `static int instantiationCounter` ou `static AtomicInteger instantiationCounter` ) e incrementar o valor toda vez que o construtor for chamado. Seguindo o padrão `factory` você pode fazer coisas interessantes como armazenar a quantidade de instanciações globais vs quantidade de instanciações locais (varíavel no escopo da factory), etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você vai criar um membro estático na classe que guardará o contador de instâncias.

No construtor vai incrementar este contador.

Só precisa saber quantas **foram** instanciadas ou precisa saber quantas **estão** instanciadas? Se precisar da segunda, terá que decrementar o contador quando o objeto for destruído ou disponibilizado.

Se deve ser decrementado na destruição, provavelmente será feito no método `finalize()`. Se precisa fazer isto quando ele deixa de ser usado, o decremento deverá ocorrer no método `dispose()` ou algo semelhante que seja chamado sempre que seja disponibilizado. Ou pode usar a interface `java.lang.AutoCloseable` na classe e o uso do objeto deverá ser feito de forma a garantir que ele seja chamado, como é o caso do padrão do [*`try` with resources*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Exemplo:

```
public class teste {
    protected static int count = 0;
    public teste() {
        count++;
    }
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        count--;
    } 
    public static int getInstanceCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/CountInstance.java).

Obviamente esta é uma implementação simplista e que terá problemas em ambiente *multithread*.

Esta operação não é atômica. Você pode ter uma *thread* lendo o contador, vamos supor que o contador valha 1. Aí outra *thread* também lê o contador que ainda vale 1. A primeira *thread* faz incremento e ela passa valer 2. A segunda *thread* faz o mesmo e ela passa valer 2. Mas se antes valia 1, então tinha uma instância, agora duas novas instâncias foram criadas por 2 *threads* simultâneas, totalizando 2 instâncias, mas o contador está valendo 2. Ocorre o mesmo no decremento, contando menos do que deve.

Para resolver isto teria que criar alguma forma de travamento, garantindo que a operação seja atômica.

Comment: Mas por que essa solução seria um problema para ambiente multithread? @bigown

Comment: @Duds editei...

Comment: obrigado @bigown

Answer (score 2):

No Java existe um modificador chamado `static` que faz com que os valores/métodos estejam no escopo da classe, e não da instancia, sendo assim você pode facilmente criar uma variável `public static int contadorInstancias = 0;` e incrementá-la sempre que o construtor for utilizado.

Você pode obter mais informações sobre `static` aqui: http://www.guj.com.br/articles/121

Answer (score 2):

Antes de mais nada você deve entender que uma **`Fábrica de Conexões`** nada mais é que uma classe que irá realizar a criação dos objetos para você, assim sendo você pode utilizar a adotada estratégia em quase 100% dos casos com o modificador `static`.

**O modificador STATIC**

Esse modificador serve para que um método ou propriedade seja relativo a CLASS e não ao OBJETO instanciado. 
Exemplo: digamos que em uma classe `ObjectFactory` possui a seguinte estrutura

```
public class ObjectFactory {
    private static int counter;
    private static ObjectFactory instance;

    public static object createInstance(TargetEnum target) {
        // ... lógica para instanciar a classe alvo
        counter++; // <-- aumentar o contador de objetos criados (este aqui não separa por tipo de objeto)
        // retornar o objeto instanciado.
    }

    // Retorna a quantidade de objetos instanciados
    public static int getQuantidadeObjetosInstanciados() {
        return counter;
    }

    public static ObjectFactory getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new ObjectFactory();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Seguindo essa idéia acima a classe pode realizar duas coisas.
A primeira é a que sempre que você usar o método `getInstance` ele sempre irá retornar o mesmo objeto independente de quantas vezes você chamar.

```
ObjectFactory obj1 = ObjectFactory.getInstance();
ObjectFactory obj2 = ObjectFactory.getInstance();

// obj1 === obj2 - sempre irá resultar em true e alteração em um alterará o outro também
```

A segunda é utilizando o `getQuantidadeObjetosInstanciados` que sempre irá mostrar o valor dos elementos instanciados

```
// ObjectFactory counter = 0
TargetClass objAlvo = ObjectFactory.createInstance(TargetEnum.TargetClass);
int qtdInstances = ObjectFactory.getQuantidadeObjetosInstanciados();
// qtdInstances = 1
TargetClass objAlvo2 = ObjectFactory.createInstance(TargetEnum.TargetClass);
int qtdInstances = ObjectFactory.getQuantidadeObjetosInstanciados();  
// qtdInstances = 2
```

Você pode combinar eles e tudo mais, mas é importante lembrar que no `finalize` da `class` seria bom você decrementar o contador.